# how to replace the second occurrent in emacs evil?

Tags: emacs

I have the following text

```
tset "abc" "123" kk
test "xyz" "345" zz
```

How to replace the second string inside double quotas? So the result should be

```
tset "abc" "replaced" kk
test "xyz" "replaced" zz
```

Comment: Is it always going to be one line each, with four categories in lower case and numbers, such that a regexp might look like?:  `^\\([a-z]+\\) +\\(\"[a-z]+\"\\) +\\(\"[0-9]+\"\\) +\\([a-z]+\\)$`  The idea is that the third category over from the left could be isolated and replaced.

Comment: This also sounds like it could be handled using rectangles:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Evil mode solution would be to use this command:

```
:g/".*".*".*"/norm 3f"lct"replaced
```

Which means:

- `g/".*".*".*"` - On any line containing the regex (which matches two quoted strings)
- `norm` - In normal mode
- `3f"lct"replaced` - go to the third `"`, move one character right, and change the text until the next `"` to "replaced"

It also takes ranges, so you can use it on a subset of lines if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to do that in an regular emacs buffer. 
I'm also assuming you want to have the second string always replaced with the same value.
Then you can use the `replace-regexp` command in emacs as follows:

```
M-x replace-regexp <RET> \(tset "[^"]*"\) "[^"]*" <RET> \1 "replaced" <RET>
```

`<RET>` represents the Enter/Return key on your keyboard.

This command searches for a string that fits an regular expression in your file and replaces it with what ever you want. The first part is set as a group, everything within the parenthesis, that you want to keep. Expressed as `\1` in the replacement string.